# Where is the declaration of CPU_ALLOC?

Tags: linux, declaration, header-files

I'm using RHEL5 kernel 2.6.33 and running GCC v4.1.2.

During my program compilation, I get the warning "implicit declaration of function CPU_ALLOC" and the error "undefined reference to 'CPU_ALLOC'. I get the same warnings and errors for CPU_ZERO_S, CPU_SET_S, CPU_FREE, numa_bitmask_alloc, numa_bitmask_setbit and numa_bitmask_free.

I understand that CPU_ALLOC should be found in sched.h, but I've searched several sched.h (/usr/include/sched.h, /usr/include/bits/sched.h, /usr/include/linux/sched.h, /usr/src/kernels/linux-2.6.33.1/include/linux/sched.h), and cannot find CPU_ALLOC.

I have tried both `#include <sched.h>` and `#include "/usr/include/sched.h"`, but I still have the errors.

I found declarations of CPU_ALLOC and the other functions on this [website](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3/CPU_ALLOC/). Is this a file that I should have on my system?

How do I resolve this problem with the CPU_* and numa_bitmask_* functions?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the following in your header file containing CPU_ALLOC.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
```